# Magento 1.3 installaton

Tags: setup, magento-1.3

i am trying to do magento 1.3 setup on local.
The setup is not fresh, its a server setup i am doing it on local
and i am getting this error. https://prnt.sc/opxr9g
Can anyone help me out please

Comment: may be your db has break, try to setup again.

Comment: @AnasMansuri now i am trying to do fresh magento 1.3 installtion and getting this error https://prnt.sc/opzafj

Comment: please check with this url - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630924/call-to-undefined-function-set-magic-quotes-runtime/46634717

Comment: @AnasMansuri I checked this, but not getting where to set set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

Comment: which php version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

hosting error I think .so check with your hosting support and request them to restore the last consistent backup of your website or any extensions issue

Comment: now i am trying to do fresh magento 1.3 installtion and getting this error https://prnt.sc/opzafj

Comment: which php version you are using  php 7?